# Run two source front-end Reactjs with one backend Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to run two sources client side are client and client_admin by react

I created directories for this like that:

```
admin
 //source reactjs (create-react-app)
client
 //source reactjs (create-react-app)
back
server.js
package.json
```

I created concurrently like this:

```
"clientonly": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run client\" \"npm run admin\""
```

but it becomes conflict because both client and admin running on PORT 3000.

Moreover, I want client run on port 3000: `localhost:3000`

but Admin will run on subpath : `localhost:3000/admin`

Any advice for this issue? Thanks

Comment: have you tried Lerna? https://github.com/lerna/lerna

Comment: @Kalaiselvan thank but I want to manage source react

Comment: Well if admin and client are essentially two different projects that get built into their own bundles, you can set the node routes to return the `index.html` of the client at the `/` path, and to return the `index.html` of the admin one at the `/admin` path.

Answer (score 0):

you can put all admin pages inside admin folder, then all client pages inside client folder
and you should have `index.js` outside both folders.
inside this file you should manage routing, Ex:

```
<Router basename={process.cwd()}>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path={join(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/admin`)}
                        render={props => <Admin {...props} />}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={join(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/:lang(en|th)?/`)}
                        render={props => <App {...props} parentFn={this.updateState} />}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </Router>
```

[image]

Comment: how index.js run outside of react src. Admin and client are different react source